# PHP Fatal error: Property $id of class MongoId cannot be read in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mongodb

I get lots of messages "**PHP Fatal error:  Property $id of class MongoId cannot be read in Unknown on line 0**" in Apache error log.

I don't know when it started to occur and can't get the reason of this error. 
The error doesn't occur while I'm visiting pages of our website having 'tail -f error.log'. When I get this message in console, I go to the page, where some user have just got fatal error and get no error.

I tried to find any answer in Google, but didn't find any mention of such problem.

Could anyone suggest, where the problem is?

Some more details:

- OS: Debian Linux (squeeze)
- PHP: 5.3.3
- MongoDB: 2.2.1
- MongoDB PHP extension: 1.2.12

Comment: you likely just changed the error_reporting level

Comment: No, we didn't change the error_reporting_level. Anyway, the error has type **fatal** which is not a "notice" or "deprecated" or any other 'low' level type.

Comment: Hmm, do you have any example queries where this has been happening? This normally denotes where the `_id` is somehow non-existent in the row since the driver will try and auto assign the `_id`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any example query since I don't know which block of code causes the problem. It's a big web project with millions of visitors, and it has lot's of queries (find, Map/Reduce, insert, update, etc) and there is no any common pattern (or I haven't noticed it) in URL/params/time, which could help to localize the problem. :(

Comment: Do you use any framework like cake or lithium? I would guess it is caused by a specific view in your Site which is not often fetched by users. Maybe a query caused by embedding and the embedded reference is empty?

Comment: No, we don't use other frameworks, since we have our own tools. We upgraded the extension to version 1.3.0, and the situation became a bit weird. After 3-4 days after the upgrade the error disappeared. I watch error logs daily and hope that unexplainable error doesn't come back. :)

Comment: Check your extensions. Maybe a go able way is to disable all not needed extensions in your php.ini or disable all and enable one by one until it crashes.

Comment: That would be possible is those errors appeared on some test server. Since those servers are used in production, we can't stop them and get into the experiments with the extensions installed. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to disable this problem adding setting `zend.enable_gc = Off` to your php.ini.
Don't ask why but it seems to be a php bug...

Comment: Will it solve the problem or just make it not to claim to logs?

Comment: This directive will turn off the automatic garbage collection which i think have a bug and kills your property. I had similar error with properties _code_ and _message_ of class _Exception_.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My mistake was to ask the question before reading the manual, and I'm sorry for that. That setting turned off seems to solve the problem. We need some more time examine the application, but for now everything looks OK.